# Access token request results in 302 in Angular HttpClient

Tags: wordpress, angular, oauth-2.0, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to authenticate requests for WordPress rest-api using grant type `password`. OAuth2 authentication in WordPress is provided by [WP OAuth Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/) plugin.

When I request access token using Postman Chrome app the server responds with expected access token object but the similar request doesn't work in Angular. It gives status 302 and due to xhr redirect to login page, I'm not able to get access token object. I'm using Angular 5.

Here's how I request access token in Angular:

```
/* Example token url
  AuthProvider.TOKEN_URL: 
  https://www.example-wordpress.com/oauth/token
*/

const body = {
  grant_type: 'password',
  username: username,
  password: password,
};

const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(AuthProvider.CLIENT_ID + ':' + AuthProvider.CLIENT_SECRET));

this.http.post(AuthProvider.TOKEN_URL, body, { headers: headers });
```

The above request produces 302 with location header set to:

```
https://www.example-wordpress.com/login/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example-wordpress.com%2Foauth%2Ftoken
```

And then a xhr GET request is made to above location which responds with HTML of login page and hence no access token is obtained.

The similar POST request for access token in Postman works fine and results in expected access token object but I can't get it to work in Angular.

**EDIT**
While debugging I generated JavaScript code for access token request from Postman and pasted in console of Chrome after importing jQuery.
The request works as expected in console as well and no redirection occurs. The response is JSON with access token.

Here's the code Postman generated for the POST request:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://example-wordpress.com/oauth/token",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "authorization": "Basic M0wzakE3d080VmxxbXB0UUF1dUI5RkxicWxmeE8yR25Zdk4xQmxvbTp4TktTYnJ1Mno5cEp2VDFMbTNGNFhEQm10eDZzUGsya1FqZDg3VmQ2",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "46339abe-2d1a-1032-f5d8-36e3193d9a81"
  },
  "data": {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "username": "my-username",
    "password": "my-password",
    "client_id": "3L3jA7wO4VlqmptQAuuB9FLbqlfxO2GnYvN1Blom",
    "client_secret": "xNKSbru2z9pJvT1Lm3F4XDBmtx6sPk2kQjd87Vd6"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

And here's the response logged from above code:

```
{
  access_token: "rksen3p351fj0povsrpfv2eeuahrciglc3ilphhy",
  expires_in: 3600, 
  token_type: "Bearer",
  scope: "basic",
  refresh_token: "fudju8tecbnwly2e1xgfv92tykvpsniwkfpvrd7d"
}
```

I'm unable to figure out why redirection occurs when we request through Angular and not responds with access token JSON.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem at all. It was a very very silly mistake. I apologize.

I was testing with two websites simultaneously and both had similar configuration. The only difference was that one had OAuth plugin installed and other not. So when I tried to authorize the request from Angular with the website which hadn't had OAuth2 plugin installed and so redirected to the login page. The constant set for the `AuthProvider.TOKEN_URL` was incorrectly set, while when I was testing with other tools I was using correct url.

Anyway, this was all my mistake. It happens sometimes, when you don't take break. :)

Answer (score 0):

`access_token` (which I imagine is what you expect to have) isn't part of the few headers that Angular is able to read without setting up your server.

Angular only read "basic" headers such as Content-type. This is because of the default CORS configuration that only reads Cache-Control, Content-Language, Content-Type, Expires, Last-Modified and Pragma. When it comes to custom headers, you have to tell your server to expose the headers.

This is done through the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) header.

Comment: From chrome dev tools, I can confirm that for ajax request mentioned in question, the response headers are:
`cache-control: no-store
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 158
content-type: application/json
date: Fri, 18 May 2018 12:55:40 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
link: <https://example-wordpress.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
pragma: no-cache
server: nginx
status: 200
vary: Authorization,Accept-Encoding`. There's no special header, I think.

Comment: And as we've been telling you from the start, this is a server issue.

Comment: What kind of issue? Can you please elaborate? Then why it is working for jQuery ajax?

Comment: I don't know why it works with Postman, I didn't code Postman. We elaborated on both topics, I won't repeat myself over and over again until you get it. Read the comments and my answer again, and see for yourself.

Comment: Maybe I'm arguing. But not only Postman, jQuery ajax also works as I mentioned. Anyway, thanks for your response.

Comment: And what is the first sentence of the second paragraph of my answer ? `Angular only read "basic" headers such as Content-type`. Is Postman Angular ? Is Ajax Angular ? Angular is a whole framework, you can't compare it with other things. That's like saying your motorcycle has 2 wheels whereas your car has 4. They're different and serve different purposes, there's no point in comparing them.

Comment: Every HttpClient is supposed to give similar responses to similar requests. Anyway, we end our discussion.

Comment: Yeah ok sure, you're right. Let's end there. Good luck with your issue.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. It was a very silly mistake, but BTW it was not a server issue or Angular behaved any different than jQuery ajax or Postman.